# RShiny adding a module within a loop, based on user input

Tags: r, shiny, shinymodules, r-environment

I want to make an RShiny app where the user can select a folder, and then add a `navbarMenu` containing as many `tabPanel`s as there are files in the selected folder. The `tabPanel`s are made with a [module](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/modules.html). Here is an app with a button that adds just one tab with one call to the module:

```r
library(shiny)

mod_tabPanel_ui <- function(id, title) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tabPanel(
    title = title,
    fluidPage(
      h1("Module UI goes here")
    )
  )
}

mod_tabPanel_server <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    ns <- session$ns
  })
}

ui <- navbarPage(
  title = "Main Title",
  id = "tabs",
  tabPanel(
    id = "home",
    title = "Home",
    actionButton(
      inputId = "add_tab",
      label = "Add tab"
    )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  ## other server logic goes here
  observeEvent(input$add_tab, {
    appendTab(
      inputId = "tabs",
      navbarMenu(
        title = "new tab",
        mod_tabPanel_ui("mod1", "Module 1")
      )
    )
    mod_tabPanel_server("mod1")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The add_tab `actionButton` makes a new `navbarMenu` using the `appendTab` function with one call to the module `mod_tabPanel_ui`+`mod_tabPanel_server`.

Now what I want to be able to do is something like this, where the `1:3` in the for loop will be replaced with `1:number of files`:

```r
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  ## other server logic goes here
  observeEvent(input$add_tab, {
    appendTab(
      inputId = "tabs",
      navbarMenu(
        title = "new tab",
        # mod_tabPanel_ui("mod1", "Module 1")
        for (i in 1:3) {
          mod_tabPanel_ui(paste("mod1", i), paste("Module", i))
        }
      )
    )
    for (i in 1:3) {
      mod_tabPanel_server(paste("mod1", i))
    }
  })
}
```

But this results on the module never appearing in the new tabs.

I've been told that it is possible to do by using `assign` and `environment` like so:

```r
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  shiny_env <- environment()
  ## other server logic goes here
  observeEvent(input$add_tab, {
    appendTab(
      inputId = "tabs",
      navbarMenu(
        title = "new tab",
        lapply(1:3, function(i) {
          mod_tabPanel_ui(paste("mod1", i), paste("Module", i))
        })
      )
    )
    for (i in 1:3) {
      assign(paste0("dynamic_server_", i),
             mod_tabPanel_server(paste0("exp", i)),
             envir = shiny_env)
    }
  })
}
```

But this give the error message:

> Warning: Error in : Navigation containers expect a collection of `bslib::nav()`/`shiny::tabPanel()`s and/or `bslib::nav_menu()`/`shiny::navbarMenu()`s. Consider using `header` or `footer` if you wish to place content above (or below) every panel's contents.

Which does not really help me. Reading [the observeEvent documentation](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.0.3/observeEvent.html) makes me think that the problem is that the module is being created in the wrong environment of something along those lines.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working with `do.call` and `lapply`:

```r
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  ## other server logic goes here
  observeEvent(
    eventExpr = input$add_tab,
    handlerExpr = {
      n_mods <- 3
      appendTab(
        inputId = "tabs",
        do.call(
          what = navbarMenu,
          args = c(
            lapply(seq_len(n_mods), function(i) {
              mod_tabPanel_ui(
                id = paste0("mod", i),
                title = paste("Module", i)
              )
            }),
            list(title = "Tab title")
          )
        )
      )
      lapply(seq_len(n_mods), function(i) {
        mod_tabPanel_server(paste0(id = "mod", i))
      })
    }
  )
}
```